# Dynamically add style to layer with user inputs

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, sld, boundless-suite

I am trying to create an SLD dynamically using parameters accepted from user. So how could I accomplish the task of adding the dynamically created SLD to my map layer?

Please tell me how to add style to layer dynamically, I am using GXP, OpenLayers, GeoEXT, GeoServer.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options here:

1. use GeoServer's REST API to upload the SLD you create and then reference it in the WMS request (as a named style), this is what GXP does (try and edit a style with GeoExplorer and see what XHR traffic goes on) see for instance: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gxp/blob/master/src/script/plugins/GeoServerStyleWriter.js
2. if your SLD is small, you can also just append it with SLD_BODY to the WMS request (mind the length of your GET request here), this is what is done here: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Control/SLDSelect.js OpenLayers also has an iframe image tile class that allows you to use POST: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Tile/Image/IFrame.js